# Creating a Hidden popup text item in oracle forms to accept values

Tags: forms, oracle, oracleforms

I am trying to set Windows's position property and in the design I have four arrow keys for up down right and left. Now my requirement is that whenever I click an up button a pop up text should open up and ask to enter x coordinate value after entering the value it should shift that value to right or left wherever it is given.

When I close my form and reopen again it should open at the last changed position that is it should remember the last x y position and open at same position.

Any suggestions would be highly Appreciated.

Comment: where are you failing? use key-up form level trigger to show your popup.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger in each of you four keys to open a pop-up. You can store the values of x and y coordinates in a table (`TAB_COORDINATES`) with columns `X_COORD` and `Y_COORD`. Every time user enters an x and y coordinate you can simply update the columns in the table with that value. Now in your form level trigger `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` you can query the table to find the x and y coordinates and use code below to set it.

```
set_window_property(winname,x_pos, x);
set_window_property(winname,y_pos, y);
```

This way, when a user opens up the the form it would be positioned at the x and y values in the table. Remember, this x and y values would take effect at a global level i.e. all users will see it set at those coordinates unless your application has a special way of setting such parameters at a user level.